# Decode large text base64 C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm trying to decode a string (type text on sql server) which has about 3024 characters. I´m using this code but it returns a truncated decode file (not complete):

```
var decodeString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(System.Convert.FromBase64String(str));
```

Am I forgetting something? I don't understand why I'm getting a truncated string.

Comment: Maybe the original encoding wasn't UTF-8? Can you show how the string was encoded?

Comment: Is there a reason you're storing a UTF-8 string Base64 encoded? As long as you use `ntext` in SQL Server, it should be fine...

Comment: Check the raw bytes and make sure there are no zeros in it. A zero is interpreted as a null char, which denotes the end of a string. This causes most text viewers/editors to stop rendering at that point.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

Encode

```
public static string Base64Encode(string plainText) {
  var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
  return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
}
```

Decode

```
public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData) {
  var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
  return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
}
```